# Real Analysis: Determine Whether the Following Sets are Open in $E^1$, closed in $E^1$ or neither.

Tags: real-analysis, self-learning

I just need help getting started so I think I only need help with one of these.

I'm given,

{$x \in \mathbb{R} \ | \ x<0 \ or \ x>1 $}

I know I need to find some open ball (or more simply an open subset) s.t. every element of this subset is contained in the set ($-\infty,0$) and (1,$\infty$)

If I prove that both of these sets are open then I know that the union of the sets must be an open set.

So I create an open ball ($p_0 - r , p_0+r$) $\in$ ($-\infty,0$)

Then I let some $p \in (p_0 - r , p_0+r)$

I want to show that $p \in (-\infty,0)$

Is it enough to show then that p is strictly less than 0?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:x\mapsto x (x-1) $ from $\Bbb R  \to \Bbb R.$.

$f $ is continuous at $\Bbb R$, so the preimage of the open  $(0,+\infty)$, which is the set
$\{x\in \Bbb R \;\;:\; x <0 \lor x>1\} $ is an open.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to show is that for any element of the set you can find an open ball around it that is in the set.  As the union of open sets is open you can concentrate on $(-\infty,0)$ as the proof is similar for the other part.  Now assume you are given a point $x \in (-\infty,0)$.  Can you find a ball around $x$ that is in the set?  You are allowed to have the size of the ball depend on $x$.

Comment: I understand this much but I'm not sure how to properly write it out. When I create my open ball it just seems trivial that it must be in the set since the distance from 0 to the center of the open ball must be less than the radius of the open ball. So I have $|p-p_0| <r$

But where do I go from here?

Comment: I actually wrote my open ball differently so as to make it easier to look at. I used $-p_0$ instead of $p_0$ and rewrote $|p-p_0| <r$ as 
$-p_0 -p_0 < p < -p_0 + p_0 \subseteq (-\infty,0)$

Comment: You don't start with the open ball, you start with the point of interest.  If I give you a $p_0$ you then have to choose an $r$ that works.  Yes, you can just use $r=-p_0$ and be done.  You could also use $r=-p_0/2$

Comment: So is it enough to say that I can have a center point and a radius? It all seems so straightforward and intuitive but I feel like more is necessary. Like for $(1,\infty)$ I see I can always find a $p_0$ that will have some radius $r = |p_0 - 1|$

Comment: Yes, I give you a center point and you have to find a radius.  The problem would come if you were trying to prove $[1,2]$ is open and I gave you $1$.  You can't find a radius.